# Visual studio 2017 professional restarting when trying to create new R project

Tags: r, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual studio 2017 professional with no admin rights. The VS2017 installed with R Tools when i am trying to create a new R project VS2017 restarting automatically with giving error:

---

**"R evaluation failed:
   setwd('~')
   Error in setwd('~'):cannot change working directory"**

---

I even tried to open only R interactive,  there also i got same error and VS2017 restarted. I have applied some of the solutions found in forums but none of them worked. Could you have any idea on this?

Comment: Because of  the `~` in the error message I'm assuming you are on Ubuntu ? What happens if you start R directly from the terminal?

Comment: I am using Windows10 with 1809 update

Comment: Thats weird then. Because `~` is an unix thing, windows wouldn't know what to do with it. What happens if you start R from its own default GUI (i.e. tying rgui in the windows 'search')

Comment: Yeah its is opening and functioning correctly. R is located in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client"

Comment: Then your problem is due to some configuration of Visual studio 2017 professional